# Assigning templates to dynamically generated WPF controls

Tags: c#, xaml

In an application, I need to remove the default highlighting effect applied to buttons when the mouse is over them. I understand this effect can be achieved by creating a custom template without the highlight feature and applying it to your buttons. However, I don't know how many buttons are needed until runtime and therefore cannot explicitly set the template property beforehand in the xaml file.

I tried setting the template as you would in the xaml file: `Template = "{StaticResource MyButtonTemplate}"` when I created the object but this did not work.

**How can I set the template of a new Button object to a template that I specified in the xaml file?** (I have heard that templates can be defined in C# but would like to avoid this if possible as I heard it is extremely tedious).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you could use a [DataTemplate](https://www.wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html) to achieve what you want.

You could set the style property of the template and then that would apply to any button that you added to the list that the template is bound to.

Here's a quick example that I made (It's not using bindings because it's kind of late here but I'm sure you can work that part out)

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">

            <!--Remove the hover and select style of the list view because we aren't using the list in that way-->
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".35" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

            <!--Setup the design that we have for our buttons-->
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="4">
                        <Button Content="{Binding}" FontWeight="Bold"  >
                            <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                </Border>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Add the buttons to the list
            items.Add("test");
            items.Add("test1");
            items.Add("test2");
            items.Add("test3");

            //Update the item source of the list view
            //This should probably be done properly with bindings but the main question was about the xaml
            listBox.ItemsSource = items;
        }
    }
}
```

And here you can see the [result](https://gyazo.com/043cb5a57cc419f274b3926d551d6d81)